# Weak limit of the divergence of a piecewise constant approximation in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

The original problem is the following:
let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be regular and bounded, $f\in L^1(\Omega)\cap C^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\operatorname{div} f=0$. Let $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ where $f_k=\sum_{i=1}^{M(k)}\chi_{T_i^k}(x)f(x^k_i)$ where $\{T_i^k\}_{1\leq I\leq M(k)}$ is a family of $n$-simplex with $x^k_i \in T_i^k$. Hence $f_k$ is a piecewise constant approximation of $f$.

$(\star)$ Is it true that $\operatorname{div}f_k \rightharpoonup^\star \operatorname{div} f$ in $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$, i.e. weak star in the sense of measure?

Side questions involved are:

$(1)$ Is there a sequence of piecewise constant functions (possibly different form the one defined above) such that $(\star)$ is true?

$(2)$ If $(\star)$ holds what about $\lim_k\|\operatorname{div}f_k\|(\Omega)$?

My efforts are all blocked by the boundary: neither $f$ nor $\nabla f$ are bounded, hence we do not have a trace on $\partial \Omega$, and all the estimates I came up with may diverge near $\partial \Omega$. I cannot even prove that $
\sup_k\|\operatorname{div}f_k\|(\Omega)\leq C$ which would be enough to check the convergence on a dense set like $\psi\in C_c^1(\Omega)$ for which I have diverge theorem and so
$$\lim_k \langle div f_k,\psi\rangle=\lim_k-\langle f_k,\nabla \psi \rangle  =\langle f ,\nabla\psi\rangle= \langle div f ,\psi\rangle,
$$
where in the last passage I used the compact support of $\psi $ (no trace of $f$).

I tried to work out some counterexamples, using $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|^2}$ on $[0,1]^2$.
For simplicity in the calculations I tried with $f_k=\sum_{i,j=0}^{k-1}\chi_{Q_{i,j}^k}(x)f(\frac{2i+1}{2k},\frac{2j+1}{2k})$ where $Q_{i,j}^k=Q((\frac{2i+1}{2k},\frac{2j+1}{2k}),\frac{1}{k})$. I am currently lost in the calculations.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to construct a counter example where $div \ f_k$ is not bounded in $M$ (for $n=1$, $f=0$).

Comment: Uff..I see. Thought that the problem was the unboundedness and never even considered such an example. Thank you. $f_k:=\sum_{i=0}^{2^{k-1}-1}\chi_{(\frac{2i}{2^k},\frac{2i+1}{2^k})}\frac{1}{k}$ should do, and you should also be able to generalise